# Check a function is harmonic

Tags: calculus, harmonic-functions, laplacian, divergence-operator

Let $\underline{u}$ be a $C^4(\mathbb{R^3})$ (vector-valued) solution of the "displacement equation of equilibrium"

$$
\mu \, \Delta\underline{u} + (\lambda+\mu)\,\nabla \operatorname{Div}
(\underline{u}) = 0
$$ 
where $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are (usually positive) constants. How can I prove that $\operatorname{Div}(\underline{u})$ is harmonic? I have tried to consider the divergence of the above equation, thus obtaining
$$ 
\mu \operatorname{Div}(\Delta\underline{u}) + (\lambda+\mu)\Delta( \operatorname{Div} (\underline{u})) = 0
$$ 
but I can't figure out why one could claim that $\operatorname{Div}(\Delta\underline{u})=0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions from $C^4$ the Laplacian and the divergence commute (the order of differentiation for third derivatives does not matter), so we have
$$
\mu \operatorname{Div}(\Delta\underline{u}) + (\lambda+\mu)\Delta( \operatorname{Div} (\underline{u})) = 
\mu \Delta(\operatorname{Div}(\underline{u})) + (\lambda+\mu)\Delta( \operatorname{Div} (\underline{u}))=(\lambda+2\mu)\Delta( \operatorname{Div} (\underline{u}))=0.
$$